# Creating linkedlist from file and resetting the head

Tags: c, file-io, data-structures, linked-list

For an assignment I'm creating a program where a text file is read and used to create a linkedlist. I'm having issues resetting the head of the list back to its original point after all the elements have been added. I have tried assigning the head pointer to some temp pointer and reassigning it at the end but that just leads to head only pointing to the first element and the ->next is null.

My code:

```
int Counter = 0;

FILE * fileReader;

Food * newElement = malloc(sizeof(Food));
Food * ListHead;
Food * originalPointer;

char * fileOutput=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
char * Token;

char * name=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);

char * foodGroup=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
double calories=0;
char type;

fileReader = fopen(filename,"r");

 do
 {
     if (Counter == 1)
     {
        originalPointer = ListHead;
     }  

    Counter = Counter + 1;

    fgets(fileOutput,200,fileReader);

    Token = strtok(fileOutput,",");
    strcpy(name,Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(foodGroup,Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");
    calories = atof(Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");

    type = *Token;      

    newElement = createRecord(name,foodGroup,calories,type);

    newElement->next = ListHead;    
    ListHead = newElement;


}while (fgets(fileOutput,200,fileReader)!=NULL);    

return ListHead;
```

Comment: ". I'm having issues resetting the head of the list back to its original point after all the elements have been added." What's the original point? Originally it is NULL, isn't it? BTW, if every line of your file contains a record, you are missing the data from the even numbered lines since you have two calls of `fgets`.

Comment: If you keep a pointer to the head of the list, and the head node's next element is `NULL`, then either your linked list isn't being built correctly or you are not keeping the head pointer correctly. So: 1) Post a minimally compilable chunk of code related to your linked list. 2) Don't capitalize C variable names. 3) If `ListHead` is a pointer the head of your list, then do not change its value after initially set. Keep a pointer called `currentListNodePtr` and set the current node to that. Set some value called  `listHeadNodePtr` when the first node is added, and don't fiddle with it after.

Comment: @RSahu I just realized the even number thing now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you are a bit confused how a linked list typically works.  Normally a linked list has a head property that points to the first entry added, then never changes.  You might also have a tail property that points to the last entry added to make adding new entries quicker.  In your code above, what you call the head is really acting like a tail.  And so of course, you are losing your head of the linked list.

I would change your code slightly to:

```
int Counter = 0;

FILE * fileReader;

Food * newElement = malloc(sizeof(Food));
Food * ListHead = NULL;
Food * ListTail = NULL;

char * fileOutput=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
char * Token;

char * name=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);

char * foodGroup=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
double calories=0;
char type;

fileReader = fopen(filename,"r");

do
{
    Counter = Counter + 1;

    fgets(fileOutput,200,fileReader);

    Token = strtok(fileOutput,",");
    strcpy(name,Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(foodGroup,Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");
    calories = atof(Token);

    Token = strtok(NULL,",");

    type = *Token;      
    newElement = createRecord(name,foodGroup,calories,type);

    if (ListHead == NULL) { ListHead = newElement; }
    newElement->next = NULL;
    if (ListTail != NULL) { ListTail->next = newElement; }
    ListTail = newElement;

}while (fgets(fileOutput,200,fileReader)!=NULL);    
return ListHead;
```

This gives you a list head and tail.  The ListHead gets set just once for the first newElement, and remains your list head.  The ListTail gets its first set for the first newElement, and progressively moves "down the list" as newElements are added.

Comment: Wouldnt the second if statement never be invoked in this case though since ListTail is never changed outside of the if? I apologize for my lack of understanding. Im very new to linkedlists and havent quite wrapped my head around how they work

Comment: No ... the line immediately after the second IF statement always sets ListTail to the lastmost added newElement.  It always get set regardless of the second IF statement.

Comment: I don't want to be considered vain, but I did answer another prior question about linked lists recently that you may want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312467/explain-to-me-linkedlist-class-with-node-class-like-you-would-to-a-5-year-old/29312597#29312597

Comment: Thank you it works. I did happen to go over your other answer, of which i found useful. Incidentally the other part of this assignment was to implement a library of functions to operate on linkedlists. Thats where createRecord() comes from.

Comment: I just realized something. This implementation skips over reading the second line from the file and making it into a struct. Im more confused now.

Comment: Read R Sahu's comment above in your question.  You have fgets twice per loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you could use rewind() to reset the file to its original point once it has been read.